# RSI counted by my self is different than on JForex

Tags: foreign-exchange

have you experienced difference in JForex RSI indicators vs counting by yourself ?
[image]

JForex shows me 49.375, 53.324

It is EUR/USD 1 Hour, 3-Dec-2018 15.00 and 16.00

I did the counting by using:

https://stockcharts.com/school/doku.php?id=chart_school:technical_indicators:relative_strength_index_rsi

Answer (score 1):

I think that you question may be a duplicate of what was asked previously:

[RSI formula doubts](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/91969/rsi-formula-doubts/91972#91972)

Both links (yours and the one in the question in my link) refer to a StockCharts explanation.

Read my answer there.  It may address your problem.